# Job Recommendations does not change when you apply to one of them

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

Thank you Stack Overflow for the new tool **Job Recommendations**. It can help many of us, but I have just a small recommendation: I already apply to some jobs, but why does it still exist in my list?

I think it is better to remove it when you apply, or you can make it a different color so we can understand that we already apply to this job, like the actual we can apply two time to the same job.

What do you think?

Comment: I would add to this to not show jobs where you currently or previously have worked.  90% of the job postings I see are for my former employer. :-p (Please don't make me go back...)